# Progress bar upload with angular and express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, multer

I'm trying to build a file uploader with a progress bar. I found angular's way of [listening to progress events](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events) (reportProgress) as simple and useful when it comes to the documentation. But I had trouble implementing it in my project. **For some reason when I upload the image the progress shows 100% as soon as the request is sent** and doesn't show real progress.

My service.ts

```
public upload(file) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/articles/image-upload`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    }).pipe(map((event) => {
      switch (event.type) {

        case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:

          const progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
          return { status: 'progress', message: progress };

        case HttpEventType.Response:
          return event.body;
        default:
          return `Unhandled event: ${event.type}`;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

And in my component

```
  addImg() {
    this.articlesService.upload(this.file).subscribe(
      (res) => console.log(res),
      (err) => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

When it comes to the backend I'm using multer-s3 to upload files to aws clouds with express server.

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3,
    contentLength: 500000000,
    bucket: 'bucketss',
    acl: 'public-read',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: 'TESTING_META_DATA!'});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString() + randtoken.uid(16))
    }
  })
})

const singleUpload = upload.single('file');

router.post('/image-upload', async (req, res) =>{
  await singleUpload(req, res, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'File Upload Error', detail: err.message}] });
    }
    return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location});
  });
});
```

Comment: Please share your answer if you get success to fix it. Thanks